# Why is tooltip auto placement not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap's [tooltip](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js) plugin, and am having trouble getting `data-placement="auto bottom"` to work. Using `data-placement="bottom"` works as intended though. Here is what my element looks like:

```
<button class="tooltip-icon btn-icon tooltip-trigger" title="Enter Address" data-placement="auto bottom">
  <svg class="icon help">
    <use xlink:href="#help"/>
  </svg>
</button>
```

The above causes the tooltip's placement to be `top`. I also changed the DEFAULT placement value in the JS:

```
  Tooltip.DEFAULTS = {
    animation: true,
    placement: 'auto bottom',
    selector: false,
    template: '<div class="bootstrap-tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
    trigger: 'hover focus',
    title: '',
    delay: 0,
    html: false,
    container: false,
    viewport: {
      selector: 'body',
      padding: 0
    }
  }
```

Here is how I am initializing: `$('.tooltip-trigger').tooltip();`

Why isn't the auto placement working as intended?

Comment: It seems like 'auto bottom' works fine with bootstrap v3.2.0 but not with latest version: [https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13934](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13934)

Comment: @Chitrang Thanks for that find. I tried with v3.2.0 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/dca8afa333f47dcdaf44162d66a0ac18f9ea126b/js/tooltip.js) but it still does not work correctly.

Comment: Hmm.. can you share jsFiddle for your code? In the link above, they have given [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77ak3/1/) where it works fine.

Comment: @Chitrang I tried with this codepen: http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/QEoKKw?editors=1010 and it works fine in the CodePen, but not my site. I am initializing the same way, but on my site, the placement auto functionality is not working. I'm using the same tooltip.js file in both areas. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea about that.

Comment: @Chitrang Looks like jQuery UI was conflicting with the bootstrap's tooltip JS. Should I close the question?

Comment: You could keep it like this if you want. That way everyone can see and provide any input if they have any. It is up to you ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto bottom", the tooltip will display to the bottom when possible, otherwise it will display top.

Comment: That is not true. Quoting from the documentation:   

"How to position the tooltip - top | bottom | left | right | auto.
When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto left", the tooltip will display to the left when possible, otherwise it will display right."

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: You are right. thanks for correcting me. sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: According to the documentation   When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto left", the tooltip will display to the left when possible, otherwise it will display right.